# Retrieve data of multiple nodes of root node from XML file nodes into c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-core

In the XML code below there is `ProductList` root node and I want to retrieve all the data internal to that node into a variable for doing further activity.

The requirement is to gather that data and use that data through foreach loop where I store data internal to `<product>` tag gathered according to the name attribute of that tag in variable and then it will gather the data of internal element to it in.

Code:

```
<ProductsList name="root">
          <Product name="name1">
            <ProductName></ProductName>
            <ProductType></ProductType>
            <ProductServiceURL></ProductServiceURL>
            <ProductApplicationURL></ProductApplicationURL>
            <ProductLastModifiedDate>2</ProductLastModifiedDate>
            <ServerFolderPath></ServerFolderPath>
            <LocalFolderPath></LocalFolderPath>
          </Product>
          <Product name="name2">
            <ProductName></ProductName>
            <ProductType></ProductType>
            <ProductServiceURL></ProductServiceURL>
            <ProductApplicationURL></ProductApplicationURL>
            <ProductLastModifiedDate></ProductLastModifiedDate>
            <ServerFolderPath></ServerFolderPath>
            <LocalFolderPath></LocalFolderPath>
          </Product>
  </ProductsList>
```

In the above code I want to give name of `<Product>` and gather data in that tag.
Which means if I give name1 then data from first `<Product>` will get & name2 will give data from second `<Product>`

Required output:

1. For name1:

   ```
       ProductName = value
       ProductType = value
       ProductServiceURL = value
       ProductApplicationURL = value
       ProductLastModifiedDate = value
       ServerFolderPath = value
       LocalFolderPath = value
   ```
2. For name2:

   ```
       ProductName = value
       ProductType = value
       ProductServiceURL = value
       ProductApplicationURL = value
       ProductLastModifiedDate = value
       ServerFolderPath = value
       LocalFolderPath = value
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `XDocument`

```
var productName = "name2";

var xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var nodes = xdoc.Descendants("Product")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == productName);

Console.WriteLine($"For {productName}:");
foreach (var value in nodes.Elements())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{value.Name} = {value.Value.ToString()}");
}
```